# can curl no longer send emails using gmail accounts?

Tags: linux, curl, gmail

I've been using the following to test that html email templates come through formatted correctly in different clients:

```
curl --ssl-reqd   --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465'   --user '{EMAIL}@gmail.com:{PASSWORD}'   --mail-from '{EMAIL}@gmail.com'   --mail-rcpt '{EMAIL}@gmail.com'   --upload-file {FILE}
```

And all of a sudden I'm getting "curl: (67) Login denied" - the login details are definitely correct and nothing's changed on my end. My guess is that google is now blocking non SSO email logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if will solve your problem, but if you have enabled 2-Step Verification in your Google account, you have to create some [app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it - from looking into it further, on May 30th Google disabled "Less secure app access" which let you send emails using just the username/pw:

[To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to **make a new 16 digits password** specific for this application and simply change the **account password** to this new secure **app password**. Now you can create one password for each app. It will keep your account password safe and manage app passwords separately.

Login to your account to create it:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

You must enable the 2-Step Verification (https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification) to access this feature.

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no
> longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you
> to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and
> password.
>
> https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255